# Filezilla Connection error in windows 8.1

Tags: ftp

I have issue for connecting the ftp to my one of domain. but its connecting in windows 8.1 it showing error like

```
Resolving address of wdcube.com
Status: Connecting to 66.85.136.155:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 6 of 50 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 19:47. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Everytime i am getting this error..

But same ftp details are working in other windows versions..

some one provide me solution to connect ftp

Answer (score 2):

Let try increasing the time out number. 
If you are using **FileZilla**, then go to **Edit => Settings => Connection**, in **Timeout** section, increase the number of timeout in seconds between 10-9999.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBuan5sNvNI
You can try to increase the value of timeout in Seconds.
Go to Edit > Settings > connection >Timeout in Seconds >100 or more

Usually whn u have low bandwidth it takes time to connect and if you have low timeout value its gets out disconnected. try it . use video linked above for reference